# How to add header to row for each record

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I have a big file, columns separated by ";"

I have transposed this to rows, but I need to add headers to the rows.

Example

Input file

```
31561;49215;10;1196825801480000
31561;49215;12;1196825801480000
31561;48665;14;1196825806980000
```

I transpose the columns to rows using this code.

```
sed '$'!'G' file | tr ';' '\n'
```

the output i got is :

```
31561
49215
10
1196825801480000

31561
49215
12
1196825801480000

31561
48665
14
1196825806980000
```

But I will like to add headers and got something like this:

```
Status1
Information1
Line     : 31561
Point    : 49215
Code:    : 10
TB      :  1196825801480000

Status1
Information1
Line     : 31561
Point    : 49215
Code:    : 12
TB      :  1196825801480000

Status1
Information1
Line     : 31561
Point    : 48665
Code:    : 14
TB      :  1196825806980000
```

Please, can help to solve this. Thanks

I change the code like this:

```
awk -F';' '{
   print "Status1"
   print "Information1"
   print "Line     :" $1;
   print "Point    :" $2; 
   print "Code     :" $3; 
   print "TB      :" $4"\n"; 
}' file
```

it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `awk`:

```
awk -F';'  '{
   if ( NR != 1 ) printf "\n";
   print "Status1\nInformation1";
   print "Line: " $1;
   print "Point: " $2;
   print "Code: " $3;
   print "TB:", $4;
}' file
```

To use in-place editing:

```
awk -i inplace -F';' ...
...
...
```

Comment: great, PesaThe, just i modify the output desired, is there the possibility to update your code, Is there the possibility to do it using directly the file  and not after the transpose from columns to rows.

Comment: what does awk -i  inplace ? please can you explain it.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your comment. `-i inplace` edits the file in place. So the changes won't be printed on `stdout` but will be made directly to the file.

Comment: Thanks PesaThe I understand, i did it use before , only with sed -i

Comment: @user2734334 Yep, I misunderstood your comment and thought you also wanted to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

using **awk**

```
$ awk -F";" 'BEGIN{ split("Line;Point;Code;TB",array)} {print "Status1" ORS "Information 1"; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print array[i]"     : "$i; printf ORS}' file
Status1
Information 1
Line     : 31561
Point     : 49215
Code     : 10
TB     : 1196825801480000

Status1
Information 1
Line     : 31561
Point     : 49215
Code     : 12
TB     : 1196825801480000

Status1
Information 1
Line     : 31561
Point     : 48665
Code     : 14
TB     : 1196825806980000
```

`split("Line;Point;Code;TB",array)` : The split function splits the string into `array`. If you've more columns then you can mention those columns in the split statement itself and the for loop will take care of printing the output in the format you desire.

To redirect output in a new file say `output_file`

```
$ awk -F";" 'BEGIN{ split("Line;Point;Code;TB",array)} {print "Status1" ORS "Information 1"; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print array[i]"     : "$i; printf ORS}' file> output_file
```

Comment: batMan, Is there the possibility to separate exactly headers and data like my output desired and not using \t

Comment: @user2734334: yeah simply include the exact number of spaces you need instead of `\t` in print  statement, as done in updated answer.